# Use of Na2S2O3 before starch in Winkler's method

Tags: experimental-chemistry, titration

In [Winkler's method](http://serc.carleton.edu/microbelife/research_methods/environ_sampling/oxygen.html) why is some amount of $\ce{Na2S2O3}$ added before addition of starch solution turning the deep straw coloured solution pale straw?

Is it to generate $\ce{I-}$ ions needed for formation of $\ce{I3-}$ in the $\ce{I2}$ containing solution? This $\ce{I3-}$ inturn reacts with the starch to form blue-black complex.

However once we didn't add $\ce{Na2S2O3}$ and the addition of starch solution did turn the solution it blue-black.

Comment: Related: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/27450/finding-out-the-concentration-of-oxygen-in-water/27469#27469

Comment: @KlausWarzecha thanks but it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: I know :D Therefore it is just a comment, not an answer ;)