# References for studying Winkler's method and CO2 estimation by APHA method

Tags: experimental-chemistry, analytical-chemistry, reference-request

What are the best sources to study and understand

- Process (reactions involved)
- Calculation

of Winkler's method and APHA method for CO2 estimation?

Comment: Related (with source): http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/27450/finding-out-the-concentration-of-oxygen-in-water/

Comment: @KlausWarzecha The cited document is not in English.

Answer (score 2):

*Ludwig* (actually *Lajos*) *Winkler*, a chemist of hungarian heritage, published his method in 1888 in a German Journal: [*Ber. Dtsch. Chem. Ges.*, **1888**, *21*, 2843-2854](http://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k90715s/f46.image).

Given that and the fact that Hungary was part of the Austro-Hungarian Empire at that time, it isn't overly astonishing that the publication is in German, rather than in English.

A nice description in English, with a discussion of technical obstacles, but without the math or equations, was published by *Patrick G. McCormick* in *J. Chem. Educ.*, **1972**, *49*, 839-841 under the title [*The determination of dissolved oxygen by the Winkler method. A student laboratory experiment*](http://dx.doi.org/10.1021/ed049p839).